# Prevent animation queueing with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

http://samstil.es/

Hover over the image on the right-hand side to see the black overlay come up.

Rapidly hover-on and hover-off that element a dozen times... you'll see that it loops through the fade animation all dozen times.

Is there a way to prevent that "animation queue"?

EDIT: The code...

HTML:

```
        <div class="about">
            <img src="img/me.jpg">
            <div id="img-hover">
                <a href="#" id="github">GitHub - <i class="icon icon-github"></i></a>
                <a href="#" id="facebook">Facebook - <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#">LinkedIn - <i class="icon icon-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .about {

        #img-hover {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 97%;
            background: #000000;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    }
```

JS:

```
$('.about').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#img-hover').fadeIn(500);
});

$('.about').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('#img-hover').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code here. Your site will change but the question will stay and it should keep making sense.

Comment: Could you please include your code here, prepare a little fiddle maybe ? Don't link to another page.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: (or just use CSS3 transitions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.about').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#img-hover').stop().fadeIn(500);
});

$('.about').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('#img-hover').stop().fadeOut(500);
});
```